# Eclipse debug mode - always in "Introspector"

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, debugging

- This is no "timeout" error! can any one have any idea why is hapaning?
  I have Spring web application project and when I try to debug it, suddenly it stack in loop to the "`Introspector`" class.

** UPDATE - screen shot **

[image]

Comment: @S.K.Venkat No this is not my problem. the current Exaption throw becuse diffrent problem that I dont understand..

Comment: Plz add the exception stacktrace in your question.

Comment: @S.K.Venkat  I added it now